# How can I get the default images used in navigation bar?

Tags: ios

Because I want to implement some custom animations in navigation bar I decided to use a custom view instead.

I want it to look exactly like a normal navigation bar though - so I have to use the same back button and "add" image. I have normal navigation bars in other places of the app and there should be no noticeable difference.

Can I get these images somehow? If not in the system maybe somewhere in the web? Looking for this delivers me a ton of results about how to use custom images in the navigation bar, which is not what I need...

Edit: I don't want to have to instantiate a navigation bar and traverse the view hierarchy based on index etc as this is error prone. Well I could theoretically do this once for every resolution and save the imgs somewhere... but meh...

Comment: I don't know if it still works but see https://github.com/0xced/iOS-Artwork-Extractor

Comment: buttons in your custom view are of UIBarButtonItem?

Comment: @ibnetariq no just UIButton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to fetch this images from the OS.

However, there is plenty of PSDs on the internet that help designers create UI/UX designs and mockups. You can use one of them and extract images you need. Check this [one](http://www.teehanlax.com/tools/iphone/) or this [one](https://www.uxpin.com/ios8-ui-kit.html) for example.

Comment: Ahh, that's a very good idea, didn't think about that! I'll wait a bit more in case there's a better solution (probably this will not be the case).